# I want to hide the Price Set on the Event Information Page. I want it to display only on the Registration Page

Tags: civievent, price-sets, donations

We use CiviEvent to promote our on-line lectures. The lectures are free but we encourage donations. I created a Price Set with suggested donation amounts.  CiviCRM has automatically added the Price Set to the bottom of the Event information page. I don't want the suggested donation amounts to show on the main Event information page.  It should be visible only after the user clicks Register Now.
(CiviCRM 5.48.0. on Wordpress Version 6.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide them using custom styling in wordpress

```
div.crm-event-info-form-block .event_fees-section {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Which stylesheet should this go in? civicrm.css? public_html/website/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css