# I want to put DONATIONS in an online event registration page NOT event description

Tags: donations

I've looked. I can't see where the fees/donations page definition and html is. I can find event information, registration and confirmation but even fees seems to fall through the cracks (or I'm looking in the wrong place).

If I tick the box for paid event, the fees show up in the frontend but I can't find them in the backend.

This is for civicrm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Joe - i don't quite follow your description but ... if you are using a Price Set then you should be able to include a field for Donations that does not count towards the Participant Count

Comment: The scenario is: 1) page describing online lecture is displayed 2) it has a register now button. 3) don't want the price set to display on page 1) but want it to show on the page that displays when the user clicks register now. I'm not interested in the participant count, just where the price set displays.

Comment: I see you already found https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42396/i-want-to-hide-the-price-set-on-the-event-information-page-i-want-it-to-display

Comment: I think my confusion earlier came from you putting DONATIONS in the title. Seems this is just about the PRICES.

Comment: There are some old but probably still relevant comments/answers here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=20645.0.html

Comment: I see you already found civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42396/… Yes, I found that - it says what to do but it doesn't say where. I'm looking for the answer to WHERE (is the code)

Comment: The thread says "in /CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.tpl"